# Microphone has stopped working on my Windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio-recording, microphone

When I check Control Panel, it's not showing a microphone.

[image]

I tried to update the audio drivers but it's showing that it's up-to-date.

[image]

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit on a [Dell XPS 15 laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-l502x/pd.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Update will not necessarily always work automagically. Try installing drivers from DELL website.